# how to upload video in youtube use api in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I have no idea how to upload video in YouTube from iPhone installed app in objective c

please give me solution?

Conclusion:

If you have any idea about this question then please share here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to release an open source YouTube example soon, but till [then Drive sample's upload photo function](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios#step_4_set_up_the_sample) should be very similar.

Instead of creating a File, create a video basically.

Comment: Thanks for help me Ibrahim UIukaya